# Powershell Display distinguished name of OU where user exists

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

I am trying to build some error checking into a script that moves AD Users to a specific OU. Is there a way to just pull the Distinguished Name out of a Get-ADUser Cmd?

Comment: Just like any other property: `(Get-ADUser -Identity "jonhdoe").DistinguishedName`.

Comment: In case you don't have PowerShell 3.0 or higher the other, albeit more chatty method, is to use `Select-Object`. `Get-ADUser -Identity "jonhdoe" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`